# How do relationships work and how can I implement it in my project?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a User table and Institutions table. I have put made a relationship with those two in access. Inst id is now in user table as a foreign key.

In my vb form, i populate a combobox with the institution names from inst table. When I select a username from a list box, his/hers relevant details are captured into textboxes on the form. But I dont know how to capture the Institution name using the foreign key.

```
'actions when listbox selection is changed
Private Sub listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    cbInst_putData()
    cbAccountType_putData()
    If gbEditUser.Visible = True Then
        Dim selected_item As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem

        qr = "Select * FROM [User] WHERE Username = '" & selected_item & "'"
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
            cn.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(qr, cn)
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    txtFirstname_edit.Text = reader.Item("Firstname").ToString
                    txtLastname_edit.Text = reader.Item("Lastname").ToString
                    txtAddress_edit.Text = reader.Item("Address").ToString
                    txtPhone_edit.Text = reader.Item("Phone").ToString
                    Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse(reader.Item("DateofBirth").ToString)
                    txtdob_edit.Text = dt
                    txtUsername_edit.Text = reader.Item("Username").ToString
                    txtPassword_edit.Text = reader.Item("Password").ToString
                    cbAccountType_edit.SelectedItem = reader.Item("AccountType").ToString
                    cbInst_edit.Text = reader.Item("InstitutionIDFK").ToString ' this is the combobox for institution list.
                    txtDesc.Text = reader.Item("Description").ToString
                    Dim checkActive As String
                    checkActive = reader.Item("Active").ToString
                   End While
            End Using
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to store the institution name in the user table and also be able to capture it again. I did it without making a relationship before. By just having a institution field separately in the user table.

[image]

Im very new to vb. And completely new to posting on here even though ive been looking at other questions on this site. So please excuse me if my codes are bad and if im not posting properly.

Comment: Open a recordset that joins the two tables. Or set value of a combobox or listbox with InstID and that should display name. Institution name textbox should not be editable.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: *By just having a institution field separately in the user table* - er, hopefully by that you mean the user has an InstitutionId column which relates to the primary key of the Institution table..

Comment: @June7 *Open a recordset that joins the two tables* - now there's a phrase I haven't heard in about 20 years.. Please tell me you don't actually mean recordset as in the ADODB sense..

Comment: @Hishiro so I have a question.. You know as you're writing all that `txtBlahBlah.Text = reader.Item("BlahBLah").ToString` over and over (and over) again; did you think to yourself "gosh, this is tedious. Must we always do it like this or is there a way to get the computer to write this repetitive boilerplate for me?"

Comment: Okay, not a recordset object. The connection is executing an SQL statement that is opening a virtual query. Use an SQL statement that is joining the two tables so all relevant data is available.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am writing how I understand how to write it. Please enlighten me of how I can improve c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretend that my Roasters are institutions and my Coffees are Users.

I bind the list box and the combo box to the data in the Form.Load.

When the selection in the ListBox is changed we get the RoasterId (the Foreign Key) associated with the selection. Next we loop through the items in the combo box Primary Key in the ID field. When we get a match, select that item and exit the loop.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RoastersSql = "Select * From Roasters;"
    Dim CoffeesSql = "Select Top 10 * From Coffees;"
    Dim RoastersDT As New DataTable
    Dim CoffeeDT As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConGD)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(RoastersSql, cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                RoastersDT.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(CoffeesSql, cn)
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                CoffeeDT.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID" 'NOT the RoasterID, this is th PK of the Coffees table
    ListBox1.DataSource = CoffeeDT
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = RoastersDT
    UpdateUI(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub

Private Sub FillTextBoxes(item As Object)
    Dim drv = DirectCast(item, DataRowView)
    TextBox1.Text = drv("Name").ToString
    TextBox2.Text = drv("Type").ToString
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    UpdateUI(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateUI(item As Object)
    Dim RoasterID = CInt(DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("RoasterID"))
    For Each item In ComboBox1.Items
        Dim ID = CInt(DirectCast(item, DataRowView)("ID"))
        If RoasterID = ID Then
            ComboBox1.SelectedItem = item
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    FillTextBoxes(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what the code is doing. But I dont know how to implement it in mine. How my code is.. :/

Comment: I managed to do it. I dont know how to post the code here in this comment. I put another query inside the running query (i dont know how else to use 2 queries), and used another command and read the inst table. Just like you did, i assigned foreign key to an variable. and assigned ID from institution table into another variable. and then cross checked with the for each method.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Make sure that you created a relationship (one-to-many).
2. Create a new query and add both tables.
3. Add all the fields from both tables in the query (except for the foreign key).
4. Make the query the data source of your `Form`.

Comment: Can you provide some code to demonstrate what you mean? What would the query look like? How do these steps solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by query? Do you mean the Select statement?